# Exception: Invalid email: [Ljava.lang.Object | sendEmailFromTemplate

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I get this error, even if the email address is valid. I tried to remplace `createDraft` by `sendEmail`, but the error still ongoing.

Error message

```
Erreur  
Exception: Invalid email: [Ljava.lang.Object;@7a4edc0
sendEmailFromTemplate   @ Code.gs:50
```

---

```
function sendEmailFromTemplate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var selectedRow = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();

    const Nom = sheet.getRange("D" + selectedRow).getValue();
    const Matricule = sheet.getRange("E" + selectedRow).getValue();
    const Recepient = sheet.getRange("K" + selectedRow).getValue();
    const Fonction = sheet.getRange("G" + selectedRow).getValue();
    const date = new Date(sheet.getRange("C" + selectedRow).getValue());
    const FormattedDATE = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT", "EEEEE, dd MMMM yyyy");
    const FormattedDATEFR = LanguageApp.translate(FormattedDATE, 'en', 'fr');
    const Adresse = sheet.getRange("J" + selectedRow).getValue();
    const UADM = sheet.getRange("F" + selectedRow).getValue();
    const Type = sheet.getRange("B" + selectedRow).getValue();
    const Check = sheet.getRange("A" + selectedRow).getValue();
  
  if (Check !== true) {
    return Logger.log("Not sending email as check is not true in column A");
  }
  
    const TemplateTexte = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Modele_Bienvenue").getRange(4, 1).getValue();
    const fileId = "1NHqn0-1gG1fmNxfvHuYQIIbtf4aOtZQB";  // Added: Please set the file ID of the logo image.
    const blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();  // Added

    const CorpsMessage = TemplateTexte.
      replace("{Nom}",Nom).
      replace("{Matricule}",Matricule).
      replace("{Adresse}",Adresse).
      replace("{UADM}",UADM).
      replace("{Date}", FormattedDATEFR.
      replace("{Fonction}",Fonction));
    const Objet = "Confirmation date d'entrée en fonction - " + Fonction + " - " + Nom;
    const html = CorpsMessage.
                  replace(/\n/g, '<br>').
                  replace('{LOGO}', '<img src="cid:logo">');
  
  if (validateEmail(Recepient)) {

    var cc = [];
      if (Type === "Voirie") {
        cc.push("jan.bas@real.com");
        } else if (Type === "Parcs") {
        cc.push("mou.bou@real.com");
        }
    // Get all the email addresses associated with the account
    const aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();

    // Check if the desired alias exists in the list of aliases
      if (aliases.indexOf("rh@real.com") != -1) {
    const EmailDraft = GmailApp.createDraft(Recepient, Objet, CorpsMessage, {
      from: "rh@real.com",
      cc: cc,
      htmlBody: html, 
      inlineImages: {logo: blob}});
        } else {
      // Handle the error if the alias does not exist
      Logger.log("The desired alias does not exist");
          }
    sheet.getRange("M" + selectedRow).setValue(new Date());
    sheet.getRange("A" + selectedRow).setValue(false);
  } else {
    Logger.log("Invalid email address: " + Recepient);
  }
}

function validateEmail(Recepient) {
  const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(String(Recepient).toLowerCase());

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your script, it seems that the value of `cc` is an array. The value of `cc` is required to be `a comma-separated list of email addresses to CC`. I thought that this might be the reason of your current issue of `About` Exception: Invalid email: [Ljava.lang.Object;@7a4edc0`. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
cc: cc,
```

#### To:

```
cc: cc.join(","),
```

#### Reference:

- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

Comment: That's wonderful. Arigatou gozaimasu.